# Ruby filter plugin creates two records for a single input json

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

There are two conf files used to load data from 2 json files,testOrders and testItems, each containing only one document, into same index. I am trying to create parent child relationship between two documents.

Below is my conf for testorders

```
  input{
         file{
        path => ["/path_data/testOrders.json"]
        type => "json"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
      }
    }

    filter {
      json {
        source => "message"
        target => "testorders_collection"
        remove_field => [ "message" ]
         }
           ruby {
        code => "
          event.set('[my_join_field][name]', 'testorders')
        "
      }
    }


    output { 
        elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "testorder"
        document_id => "%{[testorders_collection][eId]}"
        routing => "%{[testorders_collection][eId]}"
      }
    }
```

Below is the conf for testItems

```
input{
     file{
    path => ["/path_to_data/testItems.json"]
    type => "json"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    target => "test_collection"
    remove_field => [ "message" ]
  }
}
filter {
 ruby {
    code => "
      event.set('[my_join_field][name]', 'testItems')
      event.set('[my_join_field][parent]', event.get('[test_collection][foreignKeyId]'))
    "
  }
  }

output { 
    elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "testorder"
    document_id => "%{[test_collection][eId]}"
    routing => "%{[test_collection][foreignKeyId]}"
  }
}
```

As expected the logstash creates 1 record for testOrders but creates 2 records for testItems given 1 json document each for testOrders and testItems. One document is created properly with data but other is created as duplicate and there seems to be no data. The document that is created with data not parsed looks like as follows

```
 {
        "_index": "testorder",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "%{[test_collection][eId]}",
        "_score": 1,
        "_routing": "%{[test_collection][foreignKeyId]}",
        "_source": {
          "type": "json",
          "@timestamp": "2018-07-10T04:15:58.494Z",
          "host": "<hidden>",
          "test_collection": null,
          "my_join_field": {
            "name": "testItems",
            "parent": null
          },
          "path": "/path_to_data/testItems.json",
          "@version": "1"
        }
```

Comment: Where is the code which is performing the operation?

Answer (score 0):

Defining a mapping relationship in elastic search solved the issue. This is the way to define the relationship

```
    PUT fulfillmentorder
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "my_join_field": { 
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "fulfillmentorders": "orderlineitems" 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```